# Changing location of slider bar handle with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery / Javascript to modify a slider element so that the slider handle starts at 0%, instead of in the middle. Here is an example of the element I'm trying to modify:

https://www.guidedtrack.com/programs/z3srufd/run

I notice that I can manually change the starting location of the slider handle by changing the following HTML

```
<div class="slider-handle min-slider-handle round" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuetext="Slide to answer" tabindex="0" style="left: 50%;"></div>
```

I can change `style="left:50%;"` to `style = "left:0%;"`, but I cannot figure out how to do this programmatically (e.g. within Chrome/Firefox inspector).

For example, doing

```
$(".slider-handle min-slider-handle round")
```

doesn't return any matches

I can do:

```
$('[class^="slider-handle min-slider-handle round"]').css('style', 'left: 0%');
```

which seems to work, but the actual element isn't modified at all.

What is the right code to change the DOM such that all sliders on the page start at 0% (e.g. the left-most notch?)

Comment: Careful with the selectors. When using multiple classes, all must start with `.`: `$(".slider-handle.min-slider-handle.round")`, otherwise, you'll target descendants.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I was wondering why the first code didn't return any results, but the second code did.

Comment: Still can't seem to modify anything with `$(".slider-handle.min-slider-handle.round").css("style", "left:0%;");`

Comment: Try `$(".slider-handle.min-slider-handle.round").css("left", "100%")`. Style isn't a CSS property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using multiple classes in a selector, always glue them together using `.`, otherwise your search becomes about descendants, which isn't what you want in this case.

Try using:

```
$(".slider-handle.min-slider-handle.round").css("left", "100%")
```

**Note:**

- `style` isn't a CSS property, so you can't really use `.css("style", "left: 100%;")`. As an alternative to the above solution, you can set the whole style using `.attr()`:

Example:

```
$(".slider-handle.min-slider-handle.round").attr("style", "left: 100%")
```